# Consecutive TextBoxes hide/skip one row while exporting SSRS report in Excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

In my SSRS report there are 4 TextBoxes one after another. Placing of TextBoxes as under:

`TextBox1: Location 0in, 0in Size 32.53in, 0.22in
TextBox2: Location 0in, 0.22in Size 32.53in, 0.22in
TextBox3: Location 0in, 0.44in Size 32.53in, 0.22in
TextBox4: Location 0in, 0.66in Size 32.53in, 0.22in
Table:    Location 0in, 0.88in Size 32.53in, 0.5in`

I am getting hidden rows in between while exporting in excel.

[image]

Comment: Its because the boundaries are overlapping. The easiest way to get round this is add a list with 4 rows and set the text expression in there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **.25"**.

I tested a couple of text boxes. When they were set to .25" high there were no extra rows in Excel but then I change them to be .22" high, the extra rows appeared.

[image]

[image]

With text boxes that are .22" high, an extra line appeared between text boxes 2 and 3 - even though the locations were .22" and .44". When I changed them to .25" and the locations to .25" and .5", there were no extra rows.

[image]

Apparently this is some sort of undocumented limitation in Excel. Stranger still, the issue doesn't occur after the first text box. :|